# MFC. ComboBox. ScrollBar Thumd doesn't show actual position

Tags: combobox, mfc, scrollbar

[image: Before scrolling]
[image: After scrolling]

I create comboBox with these settings (from .rc file):

`COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_NAME,6,24,96,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP`

But when i open my combobox and try to scroll by mouse wheel :
Content of combobox is scrolled, thumb of scrollbar - stay on the same place.
The same behaviour when i press scrollbar's arrow controls.

How can i trace the reason of such behaviour and fix it. Or maybe it well-known problem and have solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the combo box control in the resource editor, did you forget to size its height by dragging down on the arrow key?  Can you post a picture of what your combo looks like at run time?

Comment: added screenshot. I didn't use editor - i manually coded it on .rc file